# invalid input syntax for type time or is it

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I'm building from this tutorial

https://www.driftingruby.com/episodes/fullcalendar-events-and-scheduling

In the tutorial there is an events table.

```
  create_table "events", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.datetime "start"
    t.datetime "end"
    t.string   "color"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

Now for my app, I have a local database with data in an assignments table like so (Note the two "time" columns. I'll come back to those at the end)

```
  create_table "assignments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "shift_id"
    t.integer  "contact_id"
    t.time     "start_time"
    t.time     "end_time"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

When check my json output on both apps I can see the "start" and "end" values match up

putting a limit(20) on the output in both apps controller

```
My app:

class AssignmentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_assignment, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /assignments or /assignments.json
  def index
    @assignments = Assignment.limit(20)
    # @assignments = Assignment.where(start_time: params[:start_time]..params[:end_time])
  end
...
end

The Tutorial

class EventsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_event, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @events = Event.limit(20)
    # @events = Event.where(start: params[:start]..params[:end])
  end
...
end
```

output snippet

```
my app:

[{"id":191330,"title":"Sandbox","start":"2000-01-01T12:00:00","end":"2000-01-01T16:00:00","allDay":false,"update_url":"/assignments/191330?method=patch","edit_url":"/assignments/191330/edit"},

the tutorials:

[{"id":1,"title":"Tender Is the Night","start":"2024-03-18T13:48:29","end":"2024-03-18T22:48:41","color":"black","allDay":false,"update_url":"/events/1?method=patch","edit_url":"/events/1/edit"},
```

Now..when I turn off the limit(20) on both and run the where lines instead...

```
My app:

class AssignmentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_assignment, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /assignments or /assignments.json
  def index
    # @assignments = Assignment.limit(20)
    @assignments = Assignment.where(start_time: params[:start_time]..params[:end_time])
  end
...
end

The Tutorial

class EventsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_event, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    # @events = Event.limit(20)
    @events = Event.where(start: params[:start]..params[:end])
  end
...
end
```

And enter this url for the tutorial app

```
http://localhost:3000/events.json?start=2021-01-01T12:00:00&end=2021-01-10T12:00:00
```

And this url for my app

```
http://localhost:4000/assignments.json?start_time=2001-01-01T12:00:00&end_time=2021-01-10T12:00:00
```

The tutorial app displays fine but
On my app I get this error...

```
PG::InvalidDatetimeFormat: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type time: "2001-01-01T12:00:00"
: SELECT "assignments".* FROM "assignments" WHERE ("assignments"."start_time" BETWEEN $1 AND $2)
```

"time" being the only difference in the models between the two apps

What am I missing?
What is the right syntax for time?

Thank you for your time. (pun not intended)

Comment: One major problem with the code in this tutorials is that it just takes the user input and passes it straight into the DB query. You should not assume that the clients will actually pass input which your DB will understand - neither that they will always pass valid input. Instead parse the parameters into dates on the application side (rails) and validate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declare start_time as a `t.time` which in PostgreSQL would be the type [`time`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html) (HH:MM:SS) but you pass in a (PostgreSQL) datetime values `2001-01-01T12:00:00` and `2021-01-10T12:00:00`.  You probably want to change the the type of `assignments.start_time` from `time` to `datetime`.  If you really want time values, then you would need to pass in the possible empty interval `...?start_time=12:00:00&end_time=12:00:00` in this case.

Btw, it is really confusing that that you have columns called start_time and end_time and query parameters with the same names, yet the query parameter end_time refers to upper limit of start_time column (and has nothing to do with the end_time column).

Comment: I see what you mean. I've got "time / datetime / timestamp" all running in my head now. I need to make this so I can pass both date and time vs only time. So it seems I need to convert my DB column from "time" to "timestamp"